# Django Rest Framework - Getting a model instance after serialization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've made a serializer, and I'm trying to create a `Booking` instance from the booking field in the serializer, after I've validated the POST data. However, because the `Booking` object has foreign keys, I'm getting the error:

> ValueError: Cannot assign "4": "Booking.activity" must be a "Activity" instance.

Here's my view function:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def customer_charge(request):
    serializer = ChargeCustomerRequestSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    # trying to create an instance using the ReturnDict from the serializer
    booking = Booking(**serializer.data['booking'])
    booking.save()
```

Serializers.py where `BookingSerializer` is a ModelSerializer

```
class ChargeCustomerRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    booking = BookingSerializer()
    customer = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)

class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = '__all__'
        # I wanted to view the instances with the nested information available
        # but this breaks the serializer validation if it's just given a foreign key
        # depth = 1
```

What is the correct way to create a model instance from a nested serializer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`serializer.validated_data` should be used, not `serializer.data`

Comment: This doesn't give the instance, though.

Answer (score 34):

```
model_obj = serializer.save()
```

`model_obj` holds the model instance and you can perform actions accordingly.
or you can write `create()` or `update()` method mentioned in official doc

Deserializing objects:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#deserializing-objects